# Why does x86_64 assembly have odd syscall argument order?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, system-calls, arm64

According to the [syscall man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) in the **Architecture calling conventions** section, it states the various register orders for each architecture syscall arguments. All of them make some sort of logical ordered sense, except x86_64. For example, arm64 uses x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, then x5 in order, which seems logical and in a numeric order. But for x86_64, the order is rdi, rsi, rdx, r10, r8, then r9. That doesn't seem like much of a logical order to me, which is causing my confusion. Why is x86_64 like this?

Thanks!

Comment: next question: why do they call 32 bit jumps "near" instead of "far", when already 8 bit jumps are called "short".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal userspace order as per the x86-64 ABI is: `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `rcx`, `r8`, then `r9`. That is not much more logical, beats me how they have come up with that.

Since the `syscall` instruction clobbers `rcx`, that had to be substituted and `r10` has been chosen for that. This is at least somewhat logical :)